Vulnerable iOS UIActivity Sharing
I am learning mobile security.
I read in https://mas.owasp.org/MASTG/tests/ios/MASVS-PLATFORM/MASTG-TEST-0071/ that iOS UIActivity Sharing can be made in dangerous way.
I don't understand how this attack could be carried out.
Does anyone know how an attacker can cause damage?
I'm trying to improve my knowledge. Thanks for help

The document is suggesting that there are two risks:

An app could allow data to be shared to another application that it should not. For example, a corporate app might have share functionality to allow sales orders to be sent to email. If the activities are not limited, then the app may also be able to share to WhatsApp when only sharing to the corporate email was desired.
If an app accepts incoming data then there is a risk of malformed data which exploits some vulnerability. For example, Apple has had vulnerabilities in image processing libraries in the past. These vulnerabilities have been exploited through malformed images sent in messages. There is a potential for a similarly malformed image shared to an app to exploit a vulnerability.

The document does not describe any concrete vulnerability, rather it describes how an app's use of sharing can be assessed for potential vulnerabilities

Thank You very much Paulw11. It clarified a lot for me !!!
